# Virtual box installation issue "Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment is not supported" in AWS ubuntu 14.04 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, virtualbox, xen

I have installed Virtual box 3.2 in AWS ubuntu 14.04 instance. But while it is not running because of the issue "Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment is not supported".

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-20-204:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                           [ OK ]
 * Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules                                                              [ OK ]
 * Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS                                                  [ OK ]
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
 * Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment is not supported
```

Anyone pls help me to overcome this. Ubuntu instance is mandatory for me so is there any way to remove Xen or use some other?(my primary aim is to setup a Spika server. For that vagrant with virtual box is mandatory).

Answer (score 5):

Amazon is using Xen as hypervisor (it provide virtual machines).  Virtual box is doing the same and need access to the processor instructions and state that are already used by Xen, so your EC2 instance doesn't have access to it.

The Vagrant instruction is for the development set up on the dev machine not to be use in server set up.

You will need to follow the manual instruction to set up the server (http://www.spikaapp.com/en/build/server).

Comment: the link is down

Comment: The site is down, still have some archive in Github: https://github.com/cloverstudio/Spika

Answer (score 4):

I don't under why are you trying to install Virtual box on top of AWS EC2 ubuntu 14.04 instance? If you really want to install a virtual stack on top of EC2 you can use VM ware stack.

Xen server will be aware of the underlying existing xen server. So you can't install Virtual Box.

According to the document mentioned [here](http://www.spikaapp.com/en/build/). It clearly says to use vagrant and virtualbox for the development that is your desktop or local.

You can use it on Amazon EC2 ubuntu 13.04 for production.

You are not suppose to install vagrant and virtual box on EC2. Its for development on your local box

Comment: http://www.spikaapp.com/en/build/ pls to through this link. It is their requirement. And now i have a doubt that VM ware stack is other option for virtual box?